# Why are O and E sometimes attached together, as in “les œufs”?

Tags: orthographe, alphabet, ligatures

I asked my French teacher last time, and she said she didn't know, but she will ask. Can anyone give clear and simple reason for this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The attachment of O and E (or of other letters) is called a typographic ligature. Ligatures were often used in ancient languages (such Latin and ancient Greek) to mark a [diphthong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) or sometimes simply to make writing easier in pre-press times.

In modern French, the œ ligature is linguistic as opposed to aesthetic. It bears an important linguistic role, mainly because *oe* and *œ* are not pronounced the same. When you have an *œ* in your word, you will not pronounce the *o* and the *e* separately, like you would in *coefficient*, for example. As a rule of thumb, words of Latin origin will pronounce *œ* as `/œ/` or `/ø/` <sup>1</sup> (for example *œuf*, *sœur*, *œil*, *cœur*) and words of Greek origin will pronounce it `/e/` (like *fœtus*, *Phœnix*, *Œdipe*). There are also a few words that pronounce it as `/ɛ/` (like *œstrogène*).

<sup>1</sup> This is IPA for French, if you don't know it, there's a nice chart on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help%3aIPA_for_French).

Comment: It isn't a typographic ligature (or the substitution would be optional and could be systematic), it is a linguistic ligature.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Œ in and of itself is a typographic ligature, which in French is not purely aesthetic. I was talking about it in general, hence the new paragraph about modern French, but I will edit to make it clearer.

Comment: @Unfrancophone: I was about to make this same remark, before you posted it. Eventually, I abstained. It's a lexical (or linguistic) ligature and it's not purely æsthetic… but of course it *is* typographic. How could it not be?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, It is the traditional usage, see for instance [Orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/langue_etrangere-lune.html#Ligature) "Voilà pourquoi je préfère la distinction traditionnelle entre ligatures « linguistiques ou orthographiques » et ligatures « esthétiques ou typographiques » " and further he makes a distinction between "fi" and "ct" calling the first "technique" and the second "esthétique".  Here is [one source in English](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55109/12991) making the difference between lexical and typographic ligature.

Comment: I am confused. If it is a linguistic ligature, why is it often omitted? I usually see it as "oeuf" or "coeur."

Comment: @Aerovistae I would say for the same reason you see other kinds of misspellings - people don't know. They think it doesn't matter if you use the ligature or not, and in your every day life it probably doesn't, but it remains a grammatical error.

Comment: Wow, even in professional novels? That's amazing.

Comment: @Aerovistae, if the text has been professionally edited, that's surprising.  But a sad fact is that more and more editors are taking electronic source from authors and skipping on the human corrector phase.  An additional factor Kareen forgot is common with accent on uppercase letters, they are missing from typewriters and computer keyboard (in the later case you have to look for the key combinations and memorize them), combined with the fact that some character encodings used up to the mid 2000's were missing "œ" (but not "æ").

Comment: BTW, the story about the fact that "œ" is missing from IS-8859-1 is that the French representative didn't know it was a linguistic ligature and agreed to its removal.

Comment: @Aerovistae - anpther reason why you don't see it that often is many software simply doesn't support it (not to mention keyboards or the combination of both), although it's getting better.

Comment: this is a really old post I know, but I wanted to say the Œ from Œdipe is pronounced as ø in France

Comment: Should I use it when handwriting as well?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Ideally, yes. You basically just have to make the letters touch, doesn't have to be anything fancy.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, the "oe" together tells you how that vowel is to be pronounced, as in the word "œuvre". Think of it as an extra vowel that has it's own distinct spoken sound (pronunciation). I remember learning this in elementary school. Hope that helps.

Comment: But isn't "œuvre" pronounced the same as "euvre" would be? I didn't think it has its own pronunciation; ""œu" seems to just have the same pronunciations as "eu"